# Default expanded in lazy loaded mode Element UI Tree - Vue

Tags: vuejs2, element-ui

I am using element ui tree with lazy load.

I am trying to set default nodes expanded.

But seems lazy loading and expanded are not working together.

```
<el-tree :data="DocumentField" class="fullHeight" lazy :load="loadNode" :default-expanded-keys="[0]">
```

Following is the reproduction of the same.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oRQXxQ?editors=1010

So is it possible to keep default node expanded and lazy loading work only with non expanded nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `node-key` to make it work

```
<el-tree
  :props="props"
  :load="loadNode"
         :default-expanded-keys="[2, 3]"
  lazy
  node-key="id"
  show-checkbox>
</el-tree>
```

Demo on [codepen](https://codepen.io/ittus/pen/qGQrpP)